# Another variable as the size of the array

Tags: c++, arrays, int, size

How to use the the value stored in a int variable as the size of my array

eg.

```
int a = 40;
int b[a]; // a = 40
```

Comment: This is not valid in `c++` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1887097/why-arent-variable-length-arrays-part-of-the-c-standard

Comment: [Variable-length arrays](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable-length_array) are not supported in C++ (though some compilers add it as a non-portable extension). Use [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) instead.

Comment: That has been asked and answered many many many times.

Answer (score 10):

You can't; not in standard C++ anyway, unless `a` is a `constexpr` or `const` integral type with a positive value.

The best alternative is a `std::vector<int> b(a);`

Comment: `constexpr` is not necessary for `a` to be a constant expression. `const int a = 40;` would be sufficient in this case. That said, I don't see a reason not to use `constexpr`.

Comment: @eerorika: Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 5):

Create an array with `new[]`:

```
int *b = new int[a];
```

but remember to delete it later with:

```
delete[] b;
```

A better alternative is the std container, like [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).